# React infinite scroll keeps making requests forever

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I am using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller for loading more when scroll reaches the end.

My code looks as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import FourthView from '../fourthview/fourthview.component';
import {Bootstrap, Grid, Row, Col, Button, Image, Modal, Popover} from 'react-bootstrap';
import traineeship from './traineeship.api';
import Header from '../header/header.component';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

require('./traineeship.style.scss');

class Traineeship extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            companies: [],
            page: 0,
            resetResult: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCompanies(this.state.page);
    }

    fetchCompanies = page => {
        traineeship.getAll(page).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                const companies = Array.from(this.state.companies);
                this.setState({companies: companies.concat(response.data._embedded.companies)});
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"wrapperDiv"}>
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.rootState)}
                <div className={"flexDivCol"}>
                    <div id="header">
                        <Header/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result">
                        <div className={"search"}>
                            <h2>Harjoittelupaikkoja</h2>
                            <p className={"secondaryColor"}>{this.state.companies.length} paikkaa löydetty</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"filters"}>
                            <h5 style={{marginTop: '30px', marginBottom: '10px'}} className={"primaryColor"}>
                                Hakukriteerit</h5>
                            <div className={"filter"}>Ravintola- ja cateringala</div>
                            <div className={"filter"}>Tarjoilija</div>
                            <div className={"filter"}>Kaikki</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"searchResults"}>
                            <h5 style={{marginTop: '30px', marginBottom: '10px'}} className={"primaryColor"}>
                                Hakutulokset</h5>

                            <InfiniteScroll
                                pageStart={0}
                                loadMore={ this.fetchCompanies }
                                hasMore={true || false}
                                loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
                                useWindow={false}
                            >
                                {
                                    this.state.companies.map((traineeship, key) => (
                                        <div id={"item"} key={key}>
                                            <div className={"companyInfo"}>
                                                <div className={"heading"}>
                                                    <div id={"companyDiv"}>
                                                        <p style={{
                                                            fontSize: '18px',
                                                            lineHeight: '18px'
                                                        }}>{traineeship.name}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    {
                                                        traineeship.video == null
                                                            ? ''
                                                            :
                                                            <div id={"videoDiv"}>
                                                                <div className={"youtubeBox center"}>
                                                                    <div id={"youtubeIcon"}>
                                                                        <a className={"primaryColor"}
                                                                           href={traineeship.mediaUrl}>
                                                                        <span style={{marginRight: '3px'}}><Image
                                                                            src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png"
                                                                            style={{
                                                                                width: '24px',
                                                                                height: '17px'
                                                                            }}/></span>
                                                                            <span> <p style={{
                                                                                fontSize: '13px',
                                                                                lineHeight: '18px',
                                                                                margin: 0,
                                                                                display: 'inline-block'
                                                                            }}>Esittely</p></span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div id={"txtVideo"}>

                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                    }

                                                </div>
                                                <div className={"location"}>
                                                    <div id={"locationIcon"}>
                                                        <Image src="assets/img/icLocation.png"
                                                               style={{marginTop: '-7px'}}/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id={"address"}>
                                                        <a href={"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + encodeURI("Fredrikinkatu 4, Helsinki")}>
                                                            <p className={"primaryColor"}
                                                               style={{fontSize: '13px'}}>{traineeship.city}(show in
                                                                map)</p>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className={"companyDescription"}>
                                                    <p className={"secondaryColor"} style={{
                                                        fontSize: '14px',
                                                        lineHeight: '20px'
                                                    }}>{traineeship.description}</p>
                                                </div>

                                                <div className={"companyContacts"} style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>URL: {traineeship.website}</p>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>Email: {traineeship.email}</p>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>Puh: {traineeship.phonenumber}</p>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>Contact: {traineeship.contact}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </InfiniteScroll>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Traineeship;
```

The problem is that it keep calling the fetchCompanies forever. Is there any fix for this?

In the documentation there is no samples of how the loadmore function should look like.

Comment: This works for me: https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/issues/89

Comment: You can search the issues, lots of folks have come across this problem.
https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/issues

Comment: @konekoya thanks for the link, will check if this issue is somewhere

Comment: were you able to solve this? If yes can you please tell how?

Answer (score 1):

"hasMore" is always true in your case, make it false when there is no next URL.

Answer (score 0):

problem, call function in render method

```
loadMore={ this.fetchCompanies }
```

Function call in componentDidMount and set state after use this.state print in template

Comment: i didnt get you, could you be more specific please?

Comment: If this.state is change in the render method, the structure will start to work again and again,

Comment: this.state change, you can change it state in componentDidMount component event (componentDidMount method)

Comment: loadMore={loadFunc} maybe load more event trigger function, like click load more button

Comment: react documentation: loadMore Function  A callback when more items are requested by the user. Receives a single parameter specifying the page to load e.g. function handleLoadMore(page) { /* load more items here */ } }

Comment: I'm not sure loadMore parameter, but if you do something in the render function that causes a state change, this will trigger a loop

Comment: Try to make state changes under the componentWillReceiveProps event method (componentWillReceiveProps(){......})